# Am I missing something when Trimming/truncating?

Tags: python, pandas, trim

I can't seem to see what is wrong here. I have a Pandas `Series` of length (16110) and a `DataFrame` of shape (13, 16116). I am simply trying to trim the `DataFrame` to the length of my `Series`.

I thought this would be a simple matter of:

```
df = df[:len(series)]
```

This code runs with no error, but doesn't seem to do much in the way of shortening.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: `df.loc[:,:len(series)]`

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you want [`DataFrame.head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html#pandas.DataFrame.head).

It's a convenience method; basically `head(self, n)` returns `self.iloc[:n]`.

Please note that this is *not* cutting the original frame. It returns a view (subset) of the original frame, as much as I can tell. Some  kinds of slicing return copies; [it depends on context and is not very easy to predict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-integer).

Comment: Makes sense, so I'm extending it.

Comment: This also won't get the asker what they're looking for...

Comment: @RCA: I think anything `iloc`-based won't actually cut the frame. But slicing of a regular Python list won't cut it either, so the expected behavior of `foo = bar[:bound]` is "giving a shorter representation" and not "freeing up unused parts" anyway.

Comment: Your longer answer makes sense.

Comment: This answer will not work with the input provided. The df is of shape (13, 16116) - We are slicing for columns and not rows. The solution to this with the input provided would be `df.iloc[:, :len(series)] `

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way, using `df.truncate`:

```
df = df.truncate(after=len(series)-1)
```

Example:

```
>>> df
          0         1         2         3         4
0 -0.615868  0.367161  0.138472 -0.353085  0.953871
1  0.063501 -0.256693  0.895870  0.368182  0.156447
2 -0.148034 -0.572105 -3.030083  1.092318 -2.635359
3 -1.038899  1.198679  2.633639 -0.149085 -1.574603
4 -2.639766  1.377038 -1.263696 -1.999058 -1.540654
5  1.683478 -0.403260 -1.551362 -0.007200  0.240715
6  1.033099  0.659052 -0.306415  0.086918 -1.523796
7 -1.514313  0.117010  0.490440  0.497393  0.123755
8  0.078399  0.218355 -0.255076 -0.474265 -0.430907
9  0.868665  1.917818  1.303568  1.772729 -0.446849

>>> series
0    0.311083
1    0.498019
2   -0.671698
dtype: float64

>>> df.truncate(after=len(series)-1)
          0         1         2         3         4
0 -0.615868  0.367161  0.138472 -0.353085  0.953871
1  0.063501 -0.256693  0.895870  0.368182  0.156447
2 -0.148034 -0.572105 -3.030083  1.092318 -2.635359
```

Although, just to note, I can't reproduce your problem. For instance:

```
df[:len(series)]
```

Returns a truncated `df` as well:

```
>>> df[:len(series)]
          0         1         2         3         4
0 -0.615868  0.367161  0.138472 -0.353085  0.953871
1  0.063501 -0.256693  0.895870  0.368182  0.156447
2 -0.148034 -0.572105 -3.030083  1.092318 -2.635359
```

Comment: Maybe check the df ,shape , I think the slice the column is the key , not the row

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Also, starting with a `df` of shape `(10,5)` and a series of `len` 3, I end up with a truncated `df` of shape `(3,5)` using `df[:len(series)]` (see edited post), so it seems to be tuncating the rows and not the columns... Maybe I'm missing something though...